# Word to describe someone who is unintentionally entertaining because of their lack of eloquence or intelligence?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

Essentially an "entertaining oaf by accident", but I imagine there is a more complex word to describe that.

Answer (score 3):

The word that comes to mind for me is ***buffoon***.  As Ronald Reagan was *The Great Communicator* and Herbert Hoover was *The Great Engineer*, I always thought of George W. Bush as *The Great Buffoon*.  The Oxford Living Dictionaries defines *buffoon* thusly:

> ***[buffoon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buffoon)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> A ridiculous but amusing person; a clown.